# Как сделать скрипт на получение урона в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Сделал через `OnCollisionEnter2D`:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D enemy)
{
    if (enemy.gameObject.tag == "Red Enemy")
    {
        hpForHero -= 1;  
    }
}
```

Но тут урон наноситься только один раз при срабатывание скрипта (когда дотрагиваюсь до врага). А мне нужно, чтобы урон наносился периодически, когда герой долго стоит впритык к врагу. Пробовал реализовать через `OnCollisionStay2D`, но тогда все жизни вычитаются моментально. Думал установить задержку через  `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1)`, но не смог сообразить как сделать чтобы все работало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте при входе в коллайдер запускать корутину с вычитанием здоровья, а при выходе из коллайдера - останавливать эту корутину. Н-р:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D enemy)
{
    if (enemy.gameObject.tag == "Red Enemy")
        StartCoroutine(ToDamage());
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D enemy)
{
    if (enemy.gameObject.tag == "Red Enemy")
        StopAllCoroutines();
}

private IEnumerator ToDamage()
{
    //Отнимаем 1ед здоровья пока здоровье есть или пока корутина не будет остановлена
    while ( hpForHero > 0)
    {
        hpForHero -= 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private float timeBetweenAttack;
private float startTimeBetweenAttack 1f;


void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D enemy)
{
    if (enemy.gameObject.tag == "Red Enemy" && timeBetweenAttack <= 0)
    {
        hpForHero -= 1;
        timeBetweenAttack = startTimeBetweenAttack;  
    }
else
{
  timeBetweenAttack -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).